# Как сделать отступ текста от <div> в котором он находится?

Tags: html, css

если сделать `margin: top;` то текст будет отступаться с верху, относительно верха экрана а вопрос в том, что надо отступить от div

Comment: [padding](http://htmlbook.ru/css/padding)

Answer (score 3):

За  внутренние отступы в общем случае отвечает [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/padding), например отступы сверху это`padding-top: 1em`

[margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/margin) же это внешние отступы.

Так же есть `line-height: 3em` который по сути [междустрочный интервал](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/line-height), но тоже даст отступы, еще и между строками.

На самый крайний случай можно поставить `<br>` (перевод каретки) перед текстом внутри `div`, это сместит все содержимое вниз на 1 `line-height`

P.S. `1em` и `3em` я взял для примера, чтобы показать какой тип данных  принимают вышеуказанные параметры **css**.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91131/discussion-between-stranger-in-the-q-and-alexandr-tt).

Answer (score 1):

margin - внешний отступ

padding - внутренний

Можно сделать так:

```
<div style="padding-top: 20px">
        Текст
</div>
```

Можно сделать так:

```
<div >
    <p style="margin-top: 20px">Текст</p>
</div>
```